# multiple set gets updated while updating one state in react

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

I am new to react and I was playing with react state and components. I made this little app that takes array elements from user and randomly changes its element's position. But when I change one state another state also chances with it. I have one state called element array that contains array of numbers and another array called draw that will contain elements from element array with randomly shifted element positions.problem is when draw[] changes element[] also changes. **I don't want element[] to change**. I only want draw[] contain elements from element[] array with new position within array.

When I click on draw button, it generates array with randomly positioned elements but it also changes position of elements in element array which contains original position of elements. I dont know how element array changes when I am updating draw array

```js
const dom=document.getElementById("fn")
class Final extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        this.state={
            element:[],
            draw: []
           
        }
        this.addElement=this.addElement.bind(this)
        this.drawer = this.drawer.bind(this)
    }
    drawer() {

        // shifting logic Fisher–Yates_shuffle
        var n = this.state.element.length
        var t=this.state.element
        var temp;
        while (n !== 0) {
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(n))
            n--;
            temp = t[n]
            t[n] = t[rand]
            t[rand] = temp
        }
       this.setState( (prev)=> {
          
                return {draw:t} //update one state
         
       })
        
    }
    addElement(element)
    {
       if(!element)
       {
            return "ADD SOMETHING!"
       }
       else if(this.state.element.indexOf(element)>-1)
       {
        return "value Already Exists!"
       }
        this.setState((prev)=>{
            element=prev.element.concat(element) 
            return {element}
        })
    }
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
       
           < AddElement element = {
               this.state.element
           }
           addElement = {
               this.addElement
           }
           drawer = {
               this.drawer
           }
           />
           < Drawer draw={
               this.state.draw
            }
            />
           </div>
        )
    }
}

class AddElement extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.add=this.add.bind(this)
        this.drawIt = this.drawIt.bind(this)
        this.state={
            error:undefined
        }
    }
    add(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        const element=e.target.elements.element.value
        const v=this.props.addElement(element);
       
        this.setState(()=>{return {error:v}})
        
    }
    drawIt()
    {
        
        this.props.drawer() //calls drawer function in Final componet
        
    }
    
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.add}>
                <input type="text" name="element" placeholder="add element here"/>
                <button>Add elements</button>
                {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
                </form>
                <button onClick={this.drawIt}>DRAW IT</button>
                <p> elements inside Element array</p>
                <ul>
                    {this.props.element.map((x)=>{return <Element key={x} v={x}/>})}
                </ul>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class Drawer extends React.Component{
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
            { this.props.draw.length > 0 &&  <p>new randomly generated position of elements </p>}
                <ul> 
                    {this.props.draw.map((x) => { return <Element key={x} v={x} /> })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
class Element extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li>{this.props.v}</li>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Final/>,dom)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="fn"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript objects and arrays are passed as reference.

So basically your line

```
var t=this.state.element
```

This didn't make the copy of the array but instead created a new reference to the same array.

```
var t = [...this.state.element];
```

Using destructuring assignment you unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into unique or new variables.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're mutating your state array, you can just clone or use destructure assignment in your `drawer` method:

**wrong**

```
var t = this.state.element;
```

**right**

```
var t = [...this.state.element];
```

You can also see it working [here](http://Check%20out%20this%20[codesandbox][1].).